# How to get height of UITextView on ios 8?

Tags: ios8, size, uitextview

i want to get height of UITextView for ios 8, i try code below but value of height "0.0000"

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(280, FLT_MAX);
CGFloat expectedLabelSize = [label sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize].height;
[label layoutIfNeeded];
[label updateConstraints];

NSLog(@"test height, %f", expectedLabelSize);
```